# Cannot erase SD card with Disk Utility (El Capitan)

Tags: macos, disk-utility, disk-format, sd-card

I have this SD card that I am trying to use to backup photos on a Windows computer.

After using the SD card on the Windows computer, and copying the photos back on a safe drive, I cannot erase the SD card:

[image]

And yep, in the Info window for the card, the device is listed as "read only":

[image]

I checked the Lock Tab and it's not on Lock position... What gives?

Comment: Try executing: `sudo chown <username> /dev/disk1`, with <username> being your username. You might also try `sudo chmod 750 /dev/disk1`. These commands set the permissions, as permissions error might be the case, since the Info tab says you can only read

Comment: Thanks! Tried, no luck. Terminal also doesn't seem to recognize my username...? 
`MacBook-Pro:~ fabrice$ sudo chmod 750 /dev/disk1
Password:
MacBook-Pro:~ fabrice$ sudo chown <fabrice> /dev/disk1
-bash: fabrice: No such file or directory
MacBook-Pro:~ fabrice$ sudo chown <Fabrice> /dev/disk1
-bash: Fabrice: No such file or directory
MacBook-Pro:~ fabrice$ whoami
fabrice
MacBook-Pro:~ fabrice$ sudo chdown <fabrice$> /dev/disk1
-bash: fabrice$: No such file or directory
MacBook-Pro:~ fabrice$`

Comment: It does not recognize because you put the < and > signs in. If I were to username I'd do `John` not `<John>`. So `sudo chown fabrice /dev/disk1`

Comment: Oh! Ok, gotcha - sorry. I tried both command lines and neither did work - still can't erase in Disk Utility and SD card still read only in the Info Window

Comment: Since it is not the lock issue, try first `diskutil unmountDisk /Volumes/UNTITLED` and then try erasing the partition. Sometimes, you can also select the hardware **APPLE SD CARD READER**, going to partitions, and selecting from current, to 1 partition, formatting and applying. Should delete, and re-add a partition

Comment: `Unmount failed for /Volumes/UNTITLED`and when I select APPLE SD CARD READER the Partition option is greyed out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33396/discussion-between-thebro21-and-fabrice-d).

Comment: Check that write protect is disabled for sdcard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a reason I haven't yet understood, the card was erased just fine once I used an older version of *Disk Utility*.

When I inserted the SD Card in a computer running Yosemite, two drives mounted, one called "NO NAME" which I could click on, and one called "UNTITLED" which seemed to be a ghost file or an alias:

[image]

When using *Version 13 (606)* of *Disk Utility* (so, the version included with Yosemite), the SD Card was erased without any problem.

The ghost "UNTITLED" drive disappeared.

I am therefore led to believe that the new *Disk Utility* in *El Capitan* doesn't work the same way as the previous one, or that it failed at erasing the card in this particular situation.

Comment: Version 16 worked for me whereas version 18 did not. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 27):

A better and simpler solution would be using the command-line.

Execute the following command to identify the mount name of SD card following the pattern /dev/diskX, e.g., `/dev/disk2`

```
diskutil list
```

Say the disk name is `/dev/disk2`. Now format the card to FAT32 by running the following command:

```
sudo diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 MYSD MBRFormat /dev/disk2
```

Comment: This worked for me after Disk Utility failed and so did the SD formatter application below. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect, worked great. One thing to note is my SD card had partitions from a Raspberry Pi NOOBS install, and the OSX UI Disk Utility would only show the small (59mb) partition and not the large (16.0gb) partition. CLI worked - I needed to specify the partition scheme `disk6`, not `disk6s1` or `disk6s2` in this case.

Comment: Successfully deleted all files from my SD card But, after that when I mount the SD card all data is restored. How do I fix this.

Comment: When I try this, gettig this error in terminal, Error: -69830: This operation requires an unmounted disk

Comment: @VineeshTP I got a similar error :/ `Error: -69825: Wiping volume data to prevent future accidental probing failed`

Answer (score 7):

I had the same exact problem.  Format your card using this application: https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/index.html

Worked perfect for me.

Cheers.

Comment: SDFormatter, that's the ticket!

Comment: MacOS disk utility and `diskutil` command didn't work. I installed this application. This application reported that write-protect was enabled for my device. I disabled write protect and tried using MacOS disk utility. And it worked. Thanks Sd Card Formatter :)

Comment: Not worked for me.

Comment: Well there goes all my hope. Nothing else worked and this didn't either: "[ERROR] Failed to read existing main OEM parameters from device: 60 (Operation timed out)
Formatting failed!"

Answer (score 2):

I had to run

```
sudo diskutil eraseVolume exFAT MYSD MBRFormat /dev/disk2s1
```

to successfully format a volume on my 64G SD card.

Comment: The third parameter does not appear to be "bootable" or "nonbootable". So chnaged eraseVolume to eraseDisk . but , Error: -69830: This operation requires an unmounted disk.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. I tried with 8GB, 16GB and 32GB cards and none worked. The trick was in the SD card reader. On the left side there was a switch for physical write protection. Toggling the switch and reinserting the card worked!!

Comment: This was the issue in my case. Thanks!

`Error: -69877: Couldn't open device` is the error I was getting

Answer (score 0):

I tried a different SD card reader, and that fixed the problem.